# Get value of radio button in a group and output it to the closest element of a specific class

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I've got a page with a series of h2's and radio button groups like so:

```
<section>
<h2>Label 1: <span class="value"></span></h2>
<div>
  <fieldset class="radio-list">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Value 1">
      Value 1</label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Value 2">
      Value 2</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
</section>
<section>
<h2>Label 2: <span class="value"></span></h2>
<div>
  <fieldset class="radio-list">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="Value 3">
      Value 3</label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" value="Value 4">
      Value 4</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
</section>
```

When you click a radio button in a group, I want to get that value and display it inside the closest value span. It almost works. If I click the "Value 1" radio button, it adds it to the span next to label 1 as it should. But if I then go down and click the "Value 3" radio button, it outputs "Value 1" again. Here's my script:

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
var radioValue = $("input:checked").val();
if(radioValue){
$(this).closest('section').find('h2 .value').text(radioValue);
}
});
```

And here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tactics/bykf31e6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your code is in your `radioValue` variable assignment. `$("input:checked")` searches the document from top to bottom for a checked `input` element and stops on the first instance that it finds. As a result, every time a radio button is clicked, your code is finding only the first `input:checked` element in the document. To fix this, you can retrieve the value of the clicked radio button like so:

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    var radioValue = $(this).val();
    if(radioValue){
        $(this).closest('section').find('h2 .value').text(radioValue);
    }
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/bykf31e6/2/)</kbd>